# link button to view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am starting with xcode and objective C, maybe my quiestions are basics even repetitive but really already I was looking, please no negative votes n_n

I want to link a button to view controller

Graphically with Xcode I can make it but I need to do it programmatically

button is created with the following code

```
    UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(40, btnp, 100, 30);
    btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [btn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setTitle:@"Ingresar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.scrolling addSubview:btn1];
```

this button is in principalviewcontroller

then I wanna that

when I click the button a new viewcontroller named "viewcontroller"  is opened

how to I do?

Already I was looking and looking and looking but I have not found a solution

I have several days with this, help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showSecondViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then create the method

```
- (void) showSecondViewController {
   SecondViewController * secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: already I paste the code and does not work, the code was placed in principalviewcontroller(where the button is localized)

Comment: not work because you view controller name is not `SecondViewController`. Just change with your class name... And probably you don't have a `UINavigationController` so the push has no effect

Comment: Ok thanks you, I will try of add a navigationcontroller, thanks you